# Why is my simple swift delegate and protocol setup not working?

Tags: ios, delegates, swift, protocols

I am trying to grasp the concept of delegates and protocols in swift. So I have implemented my own `PlayableMedia` protocol with two concrete classes `BlueRayMedia` and `DVDMedia` like so:

```
@protocol PlayableMedia {
    func play()
    func stop()
}

class BlueRayMedia:PlayableMedia {

    func play() {
        println("BlueRayMedia is playing")
    }

    func stop() {
        println("BlueRayMedia has stopped playing")
    }

}

class DVDMedia:PlayableMedia {

    func play() {
        println("DVD is playing")
    }

    func stop() {
        println("DVD has stopped playing")
    }


}
```

So now I have a `DVDPlayer` class that uses this setup:

```
class DVDPlayer {

    var media:PlayableMedia // delegate property

    init(media:PlayableMedia){
        self.media = media
    }

    func didStartPlaying() {
       media.play()
    }

    func didStopPlaying() {
        media.stop()
    }

}
```

But when I try to use it like this:

```
var dvdPlayer:DVDPlayer = DVDPlayer(media: BlueRayMedia())

dvdPlayer.didStartPlaying()
```

I get (no results) in my playground console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you sure this is also a delegate question? I think this is only a protocol question. Your delegating protocol ie `PlayabeMedia` has **no** delegate property. FYI its not necessary for wherever that you have a protocol you have a delegate. Though for wherever you have a delegate you must have a protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the simple mistake I made was use `@protocol` instead of just `protocol`

So this works:

```
protocol PlayableMedia {
    func play()
    func stop()
}
```

Comment: Yep, it works. This is the best (read: simplest) example of protocol+delegate that I've seen here on Stackoverflow. Still it's not entirely clear why the protocol is needed, and why you can't just call play and stop without the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Playground println() doesn't work.
Add some other expression like let x = 5

Comment: I don't understand. Where would I use that expression in my code?

Comment: Instead of println("BlueRayMedia is playing") use let x = 5

Comment: If you show the assistant editor in playground you should get println() results.